# Creating table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My requirement is that the column `accno` has no null value and no duplicates. The name column has no nulls and accepts only A to Z (no other like number or * $). The `acctype` columns is a character that allows only ( 'S'  , 'C' ,'R') and the `balance` column has no null values. If `acctype` is S then balance should be >= 5000, when C the balance should be > 10000 and when it's R >= 5000.

I am trying to apply this with:

```
create table kcb_acc_tab
 (accno varchar2(20)
    constraint kcb_acc_Pk
      primary key, 
  name varchar2(20)
    constraint kcb_name_NN
      Not null
    constraint kcb_name_CK 
      check((name =upper(name)) and (name like '[(A-Z)]')),
  Acctype char
    constraint kcb_acctype_ck
      check (acctype in('S' ,'C' ,'R')) ,
  Doo timestamp
    default sysdate ,
  bal number(7,2) kcb_bal_NN
    constraint kcb_bal_ck
      check((aacctype ='S' and bal >=5000) or
            (acctype = 'C' and bal >=10000) or
            (acctype ='R' and bal >=5000));
```

Comment: You will need to clarify what your intention and your problem is, if you want users to provide you with an answer. What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use-case for [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501), which I think is your intention with the `like` in your constraint.

I've considerably cleaned up your statement, you were missing a comma in the definition of `kcb_bal_ck`, and I've put the constraints at the end and added whitespace. This makes it easier, for me, to see what's going on and where any mistakes might be.

```
create table kcb_acc_tab(
   accno varchar2(20) not null
 , name varchar2(20) not null
 , acctype char(1) not null -- missing size of column
 , doo timestamp default sysdate not null -- missing not null
 , bal number(7,2) not null
 , constraint kcb_acc_pk primary key (accno)
 , constraint kcb_name_ck check ( regexp_like(name, '[A-Z]', 'c' ) )
 , constraint kcb_acctype_ck check ( acctype in ( 'S' ,'C' ,'R' ) )
   -- acctype was spelled incorrectly. 
 , constraint kcb_bal_ck check( ( acctype ='S' and bal >= 5000 ) 
                             or ( acctype = 'C' and bal >= 10000 ) 
                             or ( acctype ='R' and bal >= 5000 )
                                ) -- this parenthesis was missing
   )
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35afb/2) to demonstrate.

The main difference between this and your own is `regexp_like(name, '[A-Z]', 'c' )`. This ensures that the characters in the column `name` are solely contained within the group A-Z, that is the set of the upper-case Latin alphabet. The match_parameter `'c'`, specifies that the matching should be case-sensitive. The default case-sensitivity is determined by your NLS_SORT parameter, so you may not need to specify this explicitly but it's wise to do so.

Comment: Yes, that's the one thing we've never been able to agree on as a coding standard at work @trideceth12. I prefer it this way as it's really easy to see if you're missing one. Each to their own of course.